# Alinear elementos en un div

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy intentando alinear los elementos de un `div` en mi pagina web para que estén a la misma altura, pero que los botones se encuentren pegados a la derecha.

Mi html:

```
<body>
    <div class="topMenu">
        <p>WEBISTE</p>
        <button>LOGOUT   <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></button>
        <button>REFRESH   <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
      </div>
</body>
```

Mi css:

```
    body {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.topMenu {
    width: 90%;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.topMenu p {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: darkblue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.topMenu button {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: rgb(195, 216, 255);
    text-decoration: black;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que los elementos del div no se posicionan en la misma linea imaginaria y el resultado se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También querría saber porque el cuadro que se crea del `div` es tan grande y como puede adaptarse al tamaño de los elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Como el contenedor de los elementos que quieres alinear es `display: flex` lo único que tendrías que hacer es que se centren respecto a su eje secundario (en tu caso el eje **y**, verticalmente) a través de `align-items: center`.

Para que tu menú ocupe tanto como lo que sus hijos en vez de ocupar el máximo que le permita su padre, pueces usar `display: inline-flex` en vez de `display: flex`.

```css
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.topMenu {
  width: 90%;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex; /* Para hacer que el elemento tan solo ocupe lo que sus hijos marque */
  border-radius: 30px;
  align-items: center; /* Para alinear items flexibles respecto al eje secundario */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topMenu p {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.topMenu button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: rgb(195, 216, 255);
  text-decoration: black;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="topMenu">
    <div class="contenedor-logo">
      <p>WEBISTE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor-botones">
      <button>LOGOUT   <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></button>
      <button>REFRESH   <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

Para que los botones estén posicionados a la derecha de su contenedor y el "logo" a la izquierda, encerré el logo en un `<div>` contenedor y los botones en otro, para que por medio de `justify-content: space-between` el espacio que no ocupen los elementos sea puesto entre medias de estos.

Para que la altura de tu contenedor se ajuste a la de sus hijos debes suprimir los márgenes superior e inferior que el navegador está dando por defecto a tu `<p>`, dándoles valor 0.

Comment: Siguen sin estar a la derecha en este caso y el div, aun con display: inline-flex sigue siendo mayor respecto a los elementos que contiene

Comment: Si pudieras subir un ejemplo del resultado que pretendes conseguir, estaría bien. Si le quitas el `width` a `.topMenu`, junto con `display: inline-flex` se consigue que la caja de fondo gris ocupe lo que sus hijos marcan. Pero lo de que estén pegados a la derecha no sé a qué te refieres, los botones ya quedarían pegados a la derecha

Comment: Si se quita el width, lo único que se consigue es que el contenido esté pegado, la altura sigue igual. Es fácil de entender, los botones en la esquina superior derecha y en la misma línea del texto.

Comment: Es fácil de entender si lo explicas bien. En tu pregunta en ningún momento mencionas que lo que te gustaría que se adaptase a los elementos es la altura, no la anchura. Ahora queda más claro lo que pretendes.

Comment: Claro, me refería a la altura ya que me gustaría que los botones estén pegados a la derecha uno junto al otro. No se como aportar un ejemplo de lo que indico ya que no llego a elaborarlo en mi código.

Comment: De ejemplo decía que subieses un paint o algo así con la colocación de los elementos. Pero creo que ya te entendí. Edito mi respuesta.